# to compute every product for a list of list in R

Tags: r

```
a <-list(list(1, 2), list(3, 4))
```

I want to find the product of every list with in the list 'a'. In this example, it should return sth like list(2, 12) or c(2, 12), what can I do ?

Comment: `lapply(a, function(x) prod(unlist(x)) )`

Comment: @thelatemail I really don't know why you and Akrun answer so many of these questions as comments.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  For questions that are unclear or that seems to be a clear duplicate, I leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also use `Reduce` with `vapply/lapply/sapply`

```
vapply(a, Reduce, f=prod, numeric(1))
#[1]  2 12
```

Or instead of `prod`, we can use `*`.